# Git: merge local commit with last commit from different branch

Tags: git, git-merge

In Git, I have **committed** changes in my local copy of the **master branch**. In the mean time, another person has created a **different branch** (`x`) and **pushed** some new code on it, on the online repository.

How do I **merge** my code with the code on branch `x` and then **push** it to branch `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git pull
```

to get the new branch `x`

```
git checkout x
```

to checkout the new branch

```
git merge master
```

to get your changes into your copy of `x`

```
git push origin x
```

to push your changes to `x`

Comment: Thanks! I guess between `merge` and the last `push` I should commit, right?

Comment: If there are conflicts, indeed.